# Using NIntegrate and DiscretePlot to visualize pseudodifferential operators

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, visualization, fourier-analysis

In harmonic analysis, pseudodifferential operators are a way to generalize the notions of derivatives, through the use of Fourier transforms. The basic idea being,

1. Let $u(x)\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be a Schwartz function.
2. Take the Fourier transform to get $\hat{u}(\xi)\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, since the Fourier transform is an isometry of $\mathcal{S}$ onto itself.
3. Multiply $\hat{u}(\xi)$ by a "symbol". That is, a function $P(x,\xi)\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)\times C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, with some complicated restrictions on how fast it and its derivatives can grow.
4. Take the inverse Fourier transform to get back a function of $x$, usually denoted as $(P(x,D)u)(x)$.

I know Mathematica has the F.T. built in already, but I'd like to be able to use `NIntegrate` methods for cases when the F.T. operation fails. For example, the first example I'm trying to work on involves $u(x)$ as a compactly supported function, `u[x_]:=Exp[1]*Exp[-1/(1 - x^2)]` for $|x|<1$ and $u\equiv0$ for $|x|\geq 0$ (defined piecewise in Mathematica.)

**I'm also not (yet) looking into examples outside of $\mathbb{R}^1$.**

When written out, as two integrals in $\mathbb{R}^1$, finding $(P(x,D)u)(x)$ is the same as taking
$$(P(x,D)u)(x)=(2\pi)^{-1}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i(x-y)\xi}P(x,\xi)u(y)d\xi dy.$$
Notice that at least in my first example, the bounds on the $dy$ integral can be changed to just $\int_{-1}^{1}\cdots dy$ because of the compact support on $u(x)$.

I define a symbol function, `p[x_,ξ_]`, and naively defined the function `Pu[x_]`,

> `Pu[x_]:=(1/(2Pi))*NIntegrate[p[x,ξ]*NIntegrate[Exp[I*(x-y)*ξ]*u[y],{y,-1,1}],{ξ,-10,10}]`,

as two nested `NIntegrate` functions. It was my intention to use `DiscretePlot` to sample a number of values of $x$, and get a rough idea of what `Pu[x]` looks like (plotting the real and imaginary parts separately).

This works..."okay"... Right away it spits out these errors:

> "The integrand ... has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{-1,1}}"
>
> "General::stop: Further output of NIntegrate::will be suppressed during this calculation"
>
> "NIntegrate::ncvb : NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in recursive bisections in ξ {ξ}={4.14}. NIntegrate obtained -1.05471*10^-15+1.13798*10^-10 I and 2.32456*10^-11 for the integral and error estimates."

And after a considerable amount of time, it finally prints out what I'm assuming is the correct graph. But, considering how much time it takes to get even one plotting, I cannot really play around with it at all. Changing the plot range; integrating $\xi$ over a larger interval to get a better approximation; trying new symbols, $P(x,\xi)$; etc... these are all things I would love to tweak, but simply am unable to due to the computation times.

Does anyone here have any suggestions on how I could streamline this process? I feel like this is a great opportunity to visualize results from some currently relevant mathematics. I haven't seen any pictures out there, but I'm having trouble contributing with my horribly inefficient code.

Also, naturally, if we can get the process working in $\mathbb{R}^1$, then the next step would be to get it working in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

**edit:** Thanks to the suggestions, I now have pared down my function into its real and imaginary parts, each defined with only one `NIntegrate`:

> `realPu[x_]:=(1/(2Pi))*NIntegrate[p[x,ξ]*Cos[(x-y)*ξ]*u[y],{y,-1,1},{ξ,-30,30}]`
>   `imgPu[x_]:=(1/(2Pi))*NIntegrate[p[x,ξ]*Sin[(x-y)*ξ]*u[y],{y,-1,1},{ξ,-30,30}]`

Overall though, I don't see any noticeable improvement. Maybe someone has a completely new suggestion? I wonder if there is a totally different approach I should be taking instead.

**edit 2:** So I chose my symbol to be $P(x,\xi)=\log(1+\xi^2)$ (which corresponds to the operator $\log(1-\Delta)$) and let it run it's course. Here is the graph of the original bump function and its pseudoderivative:
[image: bump pseudoderivative]

**edit 3:** And here is the same $\Psi DO$ applied to a small perturbation of the original bump function:
[image]

Comment: How is `P[x_,ξ_]` defined? (Give an example, I mean.)

Comment: Well, there could be many different symbols. The first one I tried was $P(x,\xi)=\xi$, as this should have been equivalent to simply taking one derivative classically. The limited data I was able to see seemed to roughly agree with this. The next symbol I'd like to try would be $P(x,\xi)=\log(1+\xi^2)$, or $P(x,\xi)=\cos(x)\log(1+\xi^2)$.

Comment: A couple of comments: You don't need to nest the two `NIntegrate`s: the function supports multi-dimensional integration. Second: could be a copy-and-paste error, but imaginary unit is capital `I` in Mathematica. Third: it is good MMA practice to not capitalize user-defined functions so as not to interfered with built-in MMA symbols and functions (which all start with a capital letter).

Comment: I am not sure why, but I could speed up integration by splitting the `Exp` in `Sin` and `Cos` and writing it in two integrals, one real one imaginary. I guess it depends on how `NIntegrate` handles oscillatory integrands, while intuitively I would not have expected this to change anything.

Comment: Thanks. I now have two functions, each of which is defined using only one `NIntegrate`: `realPu[x_]` and `imgPu[x_]`. Running them with the `Sin` and `Cos` separated doesn't seem particularly faster though.

Comment: Well, in case of proper convergence I do not see any difference either. On my Mathematica 6, however, it deals better with slow convergence this way; who knows why.

Comment: Since you are making plots consider using smaller than the default values for NIntegrate's options AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal .